# Randomly generating SWFLoader source

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, mxml, swfloader

I want to create a view in flex that will display a randomly generated swf.
the following code can run, but my swf isnt showing? how to fix this?

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[   
        public function random(url:String):String{
            var movieArray:Array = ['swf/maily_you', 'swf/maily_work', 'swf/maily_start'];
            var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
            var index:int = movieArray.length * Math.random(); 
            var url:String = movieArray[index] + '.swf'; 
            trace("Attempting to load", url); 
            loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete); 
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOError); 
            addChild(loader); 
            function loaderComplete(e:Event):void {     
                trace("Successfully loaded", url);
            } function loaderIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {     
                trace("Failed to load", url); 
            }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Panel width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:SWFLoader  width="480" height="320" id="loader1" source="random()"/> 
</s:Panel>
```

Comment: Does URL actually look good? if not then put `trace("Getting from Array index : " + index );` before atempting to load. What do you get? Also consider (just for tests) putting those 3 swfs in same folder as this program SWF (check if its a folder path/access issue) so if you can load `maily_you.swf` but not `swf/maily_you.swf` then you can know to use absolute URL (ie: full path name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your posted code you have some little errors :

1. If you want that your `random()` function to set the source of your `SWFLoader` object, it should return the URL of the SWF and not use that as a parameter.

```
public function random():String 
{
    // ...

    return url;
}
```

---

2. I know that your are using a `Loader` object, maybe, for test purposes but you don't need that with an `SWFLoader` object.

---

3. To use a [bindable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64c3d-7fff.html) data source (your `random()` function) in your MXML code, you can use :

The curly braces ({}) syntax :

```
<mx:SWFLoader width="480" height="320" id="loader1" source="{random()}"/>
```

The [`<fx:Binding>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mxml/binding.html) tag :

```
<fx:Binding 
    source="random()"
    destination="loader1.source"
/>
<mx:SWFLoader  width="480" height="320" id="loader1" source=""/>
```

---

So your final code can be like this :

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[   
        public function random():String 
        {
            var movieArray:Array = ['swf/maily_you', 'swf/maily_work', 'swf/maily_start'];
            var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
            var index:int = movieArray.length * Math.random(); 
            var url:String = movieArray[index] + '.swf'; 
            return url;
        }
    ]]>     
</fx:Script>
<s:Panel width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:SWFLoader  width="480" height="320" id="loader1" source="random()"/> 
</s:Panel>
```

For more, take a look on [data binding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fe7.html).

Hope that can help.